# Write the Jordan form of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form

These are the properties that apply to the operator $A$.

$k_A(x)=x^4(x-2)^4, d(A)=2, d(A^2)=4, d((A-2I))=2, (d((A-2I)^2)=3$

$d$ denotes the defect. $k_A$ is the characteristic polynomial.

I honestly don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What is "d" here?

Comment: @Timbuc Oh sorry. It's the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: Is $\;k_a\;$ the characteristic polynomial of the matrix? Please remember: not all study with *the same* notation: explain yours!

Comment: @Timbuc You have no idea... It makes searching for answers a living nightmare because someone decided that a direct English translation of some term wasn't poetic enough. Anyways, it is the characteristic polynomial. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you're right. I think it'd be a good idea to have in the site a list of more or less widely used symbols in basic mathematics and then everybody would have to abide by those symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\;A\;$ is a $\;6\times 6\;$ matrix as its char. polynomial is of degree six. Second, it has only two eigenvalues: zero, of multiplicity four, and $\;2\;$ of multiplicity two. This already means that in the matrix's Jordan Canonical form there'll be four zeros and two twos on the main diagonal.

If I understoof correctly your notation, $\;d(A)=2\iff \text{rank}\,A=4\;$ , and since any Jordan block of the zero eigenvalue diminishes by one the rank of the matrix, this means there are *exactly* two such block of size two each, so that the block for zero is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

We're thus left with the block for $\;2\;$, which can be two $\;1\times 1\;$ or one of size $\;2\times2\;$

But note the above block is nilpotent of degree two, so it'll vanish when we square our matrix, and we're given $\;d(A-2I)=2\iff \text{rank}\,(A-2I)=4\;$ , so there can **not** be one single block for the eigenvalue $\;2\;$ (why?) and it thus must split in two $\;1\times 1\;$ blocks, leading us to

$$\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}0&\color{red}1&0&0&0&0\\\color{red}0&\color{red}0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&\color{red}0&\color{red}1&0&0\\0&0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: your jordan block for the eigenvalue is not right. you need a $4 \times 4$ block. there is one chain of length $3$ and one of length $1.$ like this $\left(\begin{array}{llll} 2 &1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 2 &0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 2   \end{array}$

Comment: @Abel, I beg to difer: my Jordan block for the eigenvalue $\;\lambda=0\;$ is $\;4\times4\;$ split, as explained above, in two sub-blocks $\;2\times2\;$ . What you tried to write in mathematics didn't come up right. I added color to the sub-block to make it clearer.

Comment: How is it of degree 6? Shouldn't it be 8?

Comment: @Timbuc, the characteristic polynomial is of degree $8.$ that means the matrix and jordan form is $8 \times 8$

Comment: Yes, so I see @LukaHorvat. Either I didn't notice this or else that was changed after I began writing my answer (as I say almost immediately the char. pol. is of degree six). It doesn't matter that much though as I think that if you understood what I did you can expand the answer and work with the $\;8\times8\;$ matrix

Comment: @Timbuc I didn't edit the numbers. In any case, using Wikipedia and your answer I've managed to solve it.

Comment: @LukaHorvat, most probably I misread it. Not the first time... *sigh* ...

Answer (score 1):

let me see if i can work this out. if you have trouble following refer to my early answer for concreteness.

remember the $0 \subset N(A) \subset N(A^2) = N(A^3) \ldots.$ draw a smaller box for $N(A)$ and a bigger box containing $N(A)$ for the $(N(A^2).$  find two linearly independent vectors $u_1, u_2$ in bigger box(possible because $dim(N(A^2) - \dim(N(A)) = 2.$ the vectors $Au_1$ and $Au_2$ is now in the smaller box. that is $u_1, Au_1$ and $u_2, Au_2$ form two chains of length 2 a basis fomr the generalized eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvale zero. the jordan block will look something like 
$\left( \begin{array}{llll}0 & 1 & 0 &0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \end{array} \right).$

similarly you can do the jordan block for the eigenvalue $2.$

Comment: @Timbuc, yes you rae right. i will edit it.